# Return specific value for each value in a list

Tags: python

I want to return a specific value for each value in a list.

`list = ['sathya','varna','summi']`

I want to return values such that if my key is 'sathya' return -5, if key is 'varna' return -4.

As of now my code is:

```
def return_value():
   if key == 'sathya':
         return -5
   if key == 'varna':
         return -4
```

But I don't want to use so many if conditions. can anyone help me in this

Comment: Use [a dictionary lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) if the return value is their index.

```
your_list = ['sathya','varna','summi']
```

*Method 1*

```
def return_value(key):
    for index, key_ in enumerate(your_list, start=-5):
        if key == key_:
            return index
    return "Not found"

print(return_value('sathya')) # return -5
print(return_value('invalid item')) # return not found
```

*Method 2*(Using Dict Comprehension)

```
def return_value(key):
    return {
            value: index 
            for index, value in enumerate(your_list ,start=-5)
           }.get(key, "Not found")

print(return_value('sathya')) # return -5
print(return_value('invalid item')) # return not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary to store the values and access by key.

```
def return_value(key):
    return {'sathya': -5,'varna': -4,'summi': 'any value..'}[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use dict instead of loop check condition:

```
list = ['sathya','varna','summi']

name_to_id = {'sathya':-5,'varna':-4,'summi':-3}
for i in list:
    return name_to_id.get(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic python data structure you are looking for is a dictionary, not a list.
Dictionaries allow key-value pairing in a native way.
Example.

```
d={akey:aval}
d['mykey']=myval
```

then you can retrieve you values

```
print(d['mykey'])
```

Comment: Your `dict()` call is not necessary. `d={akey: aval}` is enough